Why can the stack collide with the heap if they are located in a virtual space that is very large in size?
If each process has its own address space and it is much larger than the physical memory of the computer, why can’t we just place the stack at the end of this address space and the heap at the beginning, keeping their growth directions towards each other? In this case, we wouldn’t have the situation where the stack collides with the heap, as they are very far apart in the virtual address space. We could simply limit their size so that they cannot request more memory than allowed. This way, there would be no problem with the stack and heap colliding. I’ve been searching for information on this topic...
process in virtual memory
For example, ChatGPT suggested the following:
"the operating system must store the range of addresses between the heap and the stack in page tables, even if virtual addresses are not used, they still need to be recorded in the table, and physical addresses are assigned as needed. If we placed the stack and heap far apart, it would lead to inefficient memory allocation because the entire range of virtual addresses would need to be reserved in the page table"
I don't understand why? If ChatGPT's explanation makes sense, why do we need to record addresses in the page table that don’t have corresponding physical memory?
I want to understand how the stack and heap are arranged in memory and why it is done this way.

Hitting the limits of virtual address space is very rare, in extremely large memory machines (of the order of 10's of TBs, unfortunately I happened to work on one of them). Virtual address space is next to infinite for most conditions, and you are bound to hit the limits of the physical memory before exhausting virtual memory. Where are you encountering such a situation where the stack and heap are colliding?

Okay, you might be talking about running 32 bit applications. Then the Virtual Address space is constrained to just 4GB, whereas the physical address space is generally more than that.

An operating system managing virtual memory using a hardware memory management unit does not have this problem.
The hardware partitions the virtual address pace into pages that are mapped onto the physical address space, where the mapping is completely controlled by software.
This way it is possible to map arbitrary many virtual pages to the existing physical pages, but this is not the whole story.
Very important is that the hardware checks access to the virtual pages. If a process tries to access a virtual page that is not allocated, e.g. during a stack overflow out of its virtual page, the hardware issues a page fault that lets the operating system trap to a handling routine. This routine would then allocate a new physical page to the not allocated virtual page, allocate it, and let the interrupted process continue. The new virtual page that extends continuously the stack in the virtual address space map then to a non-continuous arbitrary physical page.
And if by chance all physical pages are currently used, one of them is paged  out to disk to free physical memory for the extended stack.
So, if the operating system is correctly programmed, the stack can never collide with the heap.
The memory management unit is also e.g. responsible for statistics, how often and when a page has been used, which helps to find a page that can be paged out to disk. It also allows to set attributes to a page, e.g. instruction, read-only or read-write.


I don't understand why? If ChatGPT's explanation makes sense, why do
we need to record addresses in the page table that don’t have
corresponding physical memory?

The whole point for having virtual memory in the first place is to be able to allocate more main memory for processes than is currently available. If operating systems only recorded virtual memory that was already mapped to physical memory then there wouldn't be any need for virtual memory.

I want to understand how the stack and heap are arranged in memory and
why it is done this way.

Stack and heap are normal memory regions like any other. They are not arranged in any way on an memory architectural level. Processes (the memory manager of the OS included) just have different rules for them. For example a process is assigned a fixed segment of memory for its stack and this memory segment is protected from being grown into by the heap segment - this is all enforced on the operating system level. Of course this there are old operating systems which do not have such guardrails and there the stack and heap of a process could very much collide into each other.

I am talking about a 64-bit system.
For example, the heap could start at virtual address 1000 and grow upwards (-> 1001, 1002...), while the stack could be located much further away and directed downwards, say starting at address 2000 (-> 1999, 1998...).
How is the distance between the stack and heap determined, and why is it not set to the maximum possible in the virtual space by default?
If the concern is ensuring they don’t collide, why can’t we just place the stack at address 9999999999 (since virtual addressing allows this) and know that it will never collide with the heap?

You could place the stack an heap at whatever virtual adresses you like, it does not mean absolutely anything. The constraints that are in place for them are not tied to any virtua address placement schemes. Virtual addresses being spaced out or adjacent does not say the mapped physical addresses have to be proportionally spaced out or adjacent.

Also you have multiple processes running on your computer, you can place all of their stacks on the highest possible virtual address

Am I understanding correctly? For example, the OS initially reserves (records the range in the table) 1 MB for the heap (for instance, addresses from 0x08000000 to 0x08010000), and the OS ensures that the distance between the stack and the heap is sufficient for the heap's future growth, reserving a range of virtual addresses for the stack at the end or far away from the heap in the address space. As a result, only a few megabytes of addresses for the stack and heap are recorded in the tables, but their placement allows enough room for future expansion?

The stack would be more likely to be 1MB (per thread), not the heap, but that's not a given and depends on the process (not relevant here), but let's say that the stack is fixed at 1MB (some 20 address line range). Generally once it's fixed it won't be allowed to go outside the fixed memory ranges. If you somehow reach the upper address and still need to allocate more you will be facing some kind of a stack overflow exception. If there weren't such constraints you could in theory crash the whole OS with a simple endless recursion (if you run your program in kernel space).

Notice how I did not say anything about the heap here as it's not so relevant. The fact that the stack is constrained to some fixed range of addresses means that the heap could not allocate over those addresses (the heap is of course itself constrained, but differently- it can grow and shrink but again over some known memory addresses that are free)

Look at this to understand the memory layout of a 32 bit machine.
https://gabrieletolomei.wordpress.com/miscellanea/operating-systems/in-memory-layout/
The same principles apply, except that nowadays machines are 64 bit, so theoretically you have 16 Exabytes of Virtual Address space. (Although, the current generation of processors generally limit that to 256 TB).
That is more than enough for a process. The heap and stack are allocated by the runtime environment. In a Java Virtual Machine the layout might be different than that offered by the OS natively. For 64 bit architectures, you should not face this issue except when you are running 32 bit applications (limiting you to 4GB of Virtual Address space). For 32 bit applications, even if you place it at the extreme ends of the 4GB address space, you might run into situations where they collide. Although, I doubt that the OS simply allows them to overwrite each other (since it can easily keep a 4KB region between them unallocated to cause a page fault).

In operating systems like Linux, you need to consider the multithreading: each thread has its own stack allocated in the global shared virtual space of the process. The stack of the main process located at the end of the virtual address space grows on demand but the stack of the secondary threads are limited allocated memory segments (e.g. by default 8 MB in GNU C library). By default, the stack of the thread is also followed by one page protected against read/write accesses to detect stack overflows (guard page).
Moreover, the heap is not only a memory segment growing up and down. In a multithreading environment, the allocation/deallocation in the heap requires a mutex to protect the update of the internal data structures of the dynamic memory allocator. A unique mutex would serialize the threads accessing the heap. This is not efficient in multithreading/multi-core environments. Hence, the C library splits the memory space into arenas which have their own mutex. The arenas are distributed between threads to parallelize the access to the heap: one thread can allocate/free in its arena while other ones do the same in other arenas.
